# How do i provide the path to the image in this python code?

Tags: python

How and where do i provide the path in command line argument in windows?

```py
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input", help="path to the input image")
    parser.add_argument("output", help="path to the output image")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: In the command line?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe that you added the arguments incorrectly. If you want to use "input" as a flag for example, you need to lead the term with two hyphens. i.e.:

```
parser.add_argument("--input", help="Path to the input image")
```

You can also use a single letter flag like so:

```
parser.add_argument("--input", "-i", help="Path to the input image")
```

With regards to accessing the data:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
input_path = args.input
output_path = args.output
```

To pass the arguments you would do the following:

```
python filename.py --input input_path --output output_path
```

or:

```
python filename.py -i input_path -o output_path
```

Just replace input_path and output_path with you're actual locations.

Comment: so should i replace "input_path" with the whole path of the image??

Comment: You have two options:
1) You can use the full explicit path of the image so that no matter where the image and the python script are located with relation to each other the script works fine.
2) You can use the relative path of the image, (where the image is located with relation to where you're calling the python script from).